# MS Web Deploy and Late Binding

Tags: web-deployment, webdeploy

I am using the Castle IoC container in a large web project written in VS2010. We have post build events that copy the late bound assemblies from other projects into the bin folder of the web app. We use IIS to host the project. My team and I have traditionally deployed dlls, database change scripts, etc. for this project manually, but are now looking at ways to automate deployment.

I have looked at MS Web Deployment but, of course, it won't detect the late bound assemblies that are instantiated by the IoC container. I suppose could set it to include all files in the project folder, but that tends to include files that aren't needed such as readme files, code files, etc.

I am still pretty new to web deploy. Has anyone found a good way to integrate web deploy and Castle so that it automatically picks up the late bound assemblies? Is there something other than MS Web Deploy that would do it?

Thanks,
David